# How to calculate Welch PSD in pyspark using pandas UDF?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to calculate Welch PSD in pyspark using pandas UDF wrapper and scipy library.

The problem is that the result of pyspark is different (wrong) from the python result (calculate directly using scipy).

Below is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType
from scipy import signal
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

rng = np.random.default_rng()
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2*np.sqrt(2)
freq = 1234.0
noise_power = 0.001 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
x += rng.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Gilang Test').getOrCreate()

time = [float(el) for el in time]
x = [float(el) for el in x]
dat_source = list(zip(time,x))

schema = StructType([StructField('time',FloatType(),True),StructField('signal',FloatType(),True)])
data = spark.createDataFrame(data= dat_source, schema=schema)
data = data.withColumn('id', F.lit(1))

@pandas_udf(StructType([StructField('frequency',FloatType()),
                        StructField('power_dens',FloatType())]), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def welch(df):
    f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(df.values, fs)
    range_num = [float(ele) for ele in f.reshape(-1,1)]
    psd = [float(ele) for ele in Pxx_den.reshape(-1,1)]
    freq = list(np.arange(range_num[0],range_num[1],(range_num[1]-range_num[0])/len(psd)))
    y = pd.DataFrame({'frequency':freq,
                      'power_dens':psd})
    return y

trying = data.select('signal','id').groupBy('id').apply(welch)
try_df = trying.toPandas()

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.plot(try_df['frequency'],try_df['power_dens'])
plt.show()
```

Here is the result from pyspark:

[image]

and this is the correct one (calculated in python):

[image]

The Scipy Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

rng = np.random.default_rng()
fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2*np.sqrt(2)
freq = 1234.0
noise_power = 0.001 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
x += rng.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(x, fs, nperseg=1024)

plt.semilogy(f, Pxx_den)
plt.ylim([0.5e-3, 1])
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD [V**2/Hz]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello! Have you tried debugging the code and see where the Spark code is going wrong?

Comment: hi @pri, I don't see anything wrong in the spark code. It run without any error. But as you can see, the result is just different and I still don't know why. Is there anything that I posibly miss in the code?

Comment: No, so what I'm suggesting is, try with a small dataset, see if the results are different. If they are different, try to put debug breakpoints in your Spark code and python code, compare the values at different breakpoints, and see where is the difference coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Ok, I will do as you suggested and will get back to you for the update

Comment: @GilangSamudraKuswana Could you please provide only the scipy code that works (without spark), so we can compare and debug.

Comment: Hi @VladSiv, sorry for very late reply. Sure. I edited my post to include the scipy code. Thanks